# How can I make duplicate of the book?

Tags: typography

I am trying to make a duplicate of this book for personal reasons. Can anyone suggest what packages, style files (and any technical thing required)  should I use?

Comment: This really isn't an appropriate 'question' for a *variety* of reasons, none the least of which is probable copyright violation. At any rate, there isn't a right answers to this question, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: No. I am using it for personal use. I am aware of copyright violation.

Comment: *At any rate…" there are far too many usable answers to a question like this. You should be coming to the table with a question that is specific, answerable, and (ideally) shows some original research effort manifest in a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From page viii

> This book was composed in Latex using TeXshop, making heavy use of the
>   semantics package of Neergard and Glenstrup to sort out the equations,
>   Jules Bean’s boxribbonproofs package to compose the box-and-line
>   proofs, and Tatsuta’s proof package for the inference rules. I used
>   rtf2latex2e to translate my original lecture notes.

If this is not enough information, you should try to contact the author and ask for the source or at least the template without content.

Apart from this, your question seems quite vague. Please ask specific questions which we can solve and where we can see a clear effort from you. In this post, there is no research value whatsoever.

If you want to get LaTeX work like this done, you will have to hire some help. And you have to clarify the topic 'copyrights' which I haven't looked at here.

---

- The text is written in Computer Modern Bright
- The class is something like `book` or alike (as it uses `\part`s)
- The PDF version is 1.6
- The document uses `hyperref` or `bookmark`
- ... and so on.

Comment: Actually this is my first attempt at anything like this. That's why I don't know how to begin. Apologies for vagueness.